# How to acquire physical noise samples

Tags: noise

I need to obtain some real (simulated) data to indicate noise in communication system.

How do I go about it? I need it for my thesis.

I don't know if denoising a set of signals will help so I can have the noise data samples.

I  just need the noise data samples.

Comment: That's not how noise works, at all. You can, if you know it, subtract the original  signal from your observation, but *you need to know what the original signal was*, which, in digital communications, is not the case – because that's what you want to figure out to receive information.

Comment: Your question still is pretty unclear: What do you need this noise estimate for? remember, noise is already a random process – so no two realizations of noise will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to grab a set of samples of physical noise is by acquring a cheap SDR, such as an [RTL](http://www.rtl-sdr.com/), tuning it to an empty band, and just reading and saving the samples. This should give a you a nice set of mostly white noise samples.

Comment: Thanks so much @ MBaz. Pls can you just explain a little further how to go about this. Thanks.

Comment: @StephenOjo There is a quickstart guide here: http://www.rtl-sdr.com/rtl-sdr-quick-start-guide/